# how to send value of a variable declared in one jsp file to an other jsp file and how to receive it in the other jsp file

Tags: html, jsp

I have a login.html page where i get the username and password details. I use the `<form>` tag to POST those values onto `login.jsp` file for further processing. Now in `login.jsp` I have used the line
`String username=request.getParameter("username");`  to get the value.

There is an other **request.jsp** file where i need the same **username** variable value. Can anyone sugest me the code line to be used in **login.jsp** to send the value of **username** to **request.jsp** and also the code line in **request.jsp** to recieve it?

Comment: Are you including request.jsp in login.jsp? If yes how are you including it? Include the code fragment you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can try this

### Login.jsp

```
session.setAttribute("username2",username); // the username value is come from request parameter
```

### Request.jsp

```
String USERNAME = (String)session.getAttribute("username2");
```

### OR

you can bring param from login.jsp to request.jsp by passing parameter

eg. at login.jsp form tag   `action="request.jsp?username2=<%=username%>"`
   
eg. at request.jsp `String USERNAME= request.getParameter("username2");`

Answer (score -1):

You can send attributes using request object.

```
request.setAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue)
```

And receive using `request.getAttribute(attributeName)`